# How to find the probability of getting at least two hits

Tags: probability

Please could I ask for help with the following question:

*When a boy fires an air-rifle the probability that he hits the target is p.
Find the probability that, firing n shots ($n\geq2$), he scores at least two hits.*

The required answer is:

$1-np(1-p)^{n-1}-(1-p)^n$

Not sure where to start. I've verified the formula for n=1,2,3 by enumerating the possibilities and counting, but could not see a pattern emerging.

For example, with n=4 I can draw out the sixteen possibilities and see that there are six involving two misses and two hits, four involving one miss and three hits and one involving four hits leading to:

P(at least two hits when n=4) = $6(1-p)^2p^2+4(1-p)p^3+p^4$

Similarly I get:

P(at least two hits when n=3) = $3(1-p)p^2+p^3$

and

P(at least two hits when n=2) = $p^2$

All of which agree with the required answer, but I can't see how to generalize for any n.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: $(1-p)^n$ is probability of no hits. $p(1-p)^{n-1}$ is probability of hit in first shot and no hits in remaining shots. First shot in this problem is symmetric to another shots, then probability of one hit is $n p(1-p)^{n-1}$. Then probability of at least two hits is $1-(1-p)^n-n p(1-p)^{n-1}$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$P(\text{Hitting target at least twice) } + P(\text{Hitting target at most once}) = 1$$

Can you find the second term in the above equation? Maybe splitting cases?

Answer (score 2):

*Hint*

Think of the binomial distribution coupled with the use of a $\Sigma$ expression to sum up terms

Answer (score 2):

Let $X$ be the amount of hits.

Then $P(X\ge 2) = 1 - P(X<2)$.

And $P(X<2)=P(X=0)+P(X=1)$

Can you go on from here?

Comment: Thanks very much (to everyone who answered). I see it now thanks to your help.

Answer (score 0):

The probabilty the boy gets no hits at all is $(1- p)^n$.  The probablity the first shot is a hit and all succeeding shots are misses is $p(1- p)^{n-1}$.  It can be shown that, in fact, a specific shot (the second shot, the third shot, etc.) is a hit and all the others are misses is also $p(1- p)^{n-1}$.  There are n shots so the probability of one shot, in any place, and n-1 misses is $np(1- p)^{n-1}$.  The probablity of less than two hits is $(1- p)^n+ np(1- p)^{n-1}= (1- p)^{n-1}(1- np).

The probability of "two or more hits" is 1 minust that: 1- (1- p)^{n-1}(1- np).